# Import add and update products with their attributes in a CSV file and cron job Magento2

Tags: magento2.3, cron, csv, importexport, magento-cron

I am using Magento 2.3.3 and wants to import products using cron and csv. I have google Sheet which contains all products data and sheet's data changes continuously. So I have to run a cron every day which updates product price, qty and some attributes values.

1. I've generated csv from sheet and it is being successfully imported manually.
2. Then I tried to import csv using cron by hitting some import functions existing in module- import-export. But didn't work and everything messed up.
3. Now I'm trying to import products by directly save them in database.

Is it possible to do that? Or is their another way?